# End Process and Child Processes

Tags: go, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to properly terminate a command

```
c := exec.Command("omxplayer", "video.mp4")
c.Start()

// send kill signal to terminate command at later stage
time.Sleep(4*time.Second)
c.Process.Kill()
c.Wait() // should wait for program to fully exit

// start again with new video
c := exec.Command("omxplayer", "video2.mp4")
c.Start()
```

I'm trying to kill the current `omxplayer` process on my Raspberry-Pi so that I can start it again with a new video.

Once I send the `Kill` signal, I call `c.Wait()` to wait for the current command to end before starting a new command.

**The Problem** is that the first command is not stopping, but the next command is starting anyway. So I end up with multiple videos being played at the same time.

Comment: `omxplayer` is probably forking a new process. If that's the case you may have to search for its pid to signal if it doesn't provide a mechanism to shut it down.

Comment: Use `pstree -p` to view process forked by `omxplayer` (if any).

Comment: The parent process also might want to clean up, but you're not letting it by sending a SIGKILL. See what happens with a SIGTERM or SIGINT.

Comment: Can you check what errors (if any) in every step of this you're possibly getting? (you can do this by assigning them, just like: 
`err := c.Wait() 
if err != nil{log.Fatal(err)}`

Comment: Thanks guys, I think you're right, `omxplayer` is forking a new process. I've been able to correctly stop it by piping in the `q` character, which is used to **"quit"** `omxplayer`. Now that I know what to look for I've found a solution to kill the process group which seems to work as well. If one of you is interested in posting an answer like that I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: You can answer your own question - and I encourage you to do so here, as it may help others in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`omxplayer` is forking a new process. For `omxplayer` in particular, I can send the "q" string into its `StdinPipe`. That's like pressing the `q` key on the keyboard, which quits the program, ending both the parent and child processes:

```
c := exec.Command("omxplayer", "video.mp4")
c.Start()
p := c.StdinPipe()
_, err := p.Write([]byte("q")) // send 'q' to the Stdin of the process to quit omxplayer

c.Wait() // should wait for program to fully exit

// start again with new video
c := exec.Command("omxplayer", "video2.mp4")
c.Start()
```

Another more general option is to create a process group with both the parent and child processes and kill that:

```
c := exec.Command("omxplayer", "video.mp4")
// make the process group id the same as the pid
c.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{Setpgid: true}
c.Start()

// sending a negative number as the PID sends the kill signal to the group
syscall.Kill(-c.Process.Pid, syscall.SIGKILL)

c.Wait()
```

Based on [this Medium post](https://medium.com/@felixge/killing-a-child-process-and-all-of-its-children-in-go-54079af94773)